# iOS Core data - Nothing fetched right after an object is edited

Tags: ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have the following problem when fetching data right after updating an object with CoreData.

Here are some details of the issue I encounter :

- I have a "PersonDetailsViewController" in which there are 2 tableviews that contain some info about a person (each Person object is added to the CoreData context and contains among other things a name and a set of emails).
- Each row of the tablewiews is clickable and segues to a modal VC ("EditDetailsVC") that let the user update the person's info.
- Hitting "done" on the "EditDetailsVC" returns to the "PersonDetailsVC" after updating the info via the managed object in the CoreData context.
- In the "PersonsDetailsVC" 's <strike>viewDidLoad</strike> viewWillAppear, I fetch back the person's info and populate the tableviews.

It is in the final step that things are not happening the right way : sometimes the Person object is retrieved correctly from the database, sometimes nothing's fetched.

I tried both to save the context or not right after updating the object, but the same issue happens.

I assumed that this is linked to the time to access the database and maybe that data is being written the to context while I try to fetch some data in the context ?

Can you help me out here ?

EDIT :

All the following belongs to a class called "DataManager" that centralizes all the CoreData accesses.
The class uses the singleton design pattern.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext * context ;
#define DM_CONTEXT      [DataManager sharedInstance].context;
```

Here is the method that is called in viewWillAppear :

```
+(NSDictionary*) getTargetDetailsForIdentifier:(NSNumber*)identifier
{

    NSMutableDictionary * targetDetails ;

    NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Target"];
    NSPredicate * predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier =%@",identifier];
    request.predicate = predicate ;

    NSError * err ;

    NSArray * result = [DM_CONTEXT executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s : Error when fetching target details for the identifier <%@>",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,identifier);
    }
    else if(![result count])
    {
        NSLog(@"%s : Nothing found for the identifier <%@>",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,identifier);

    }
    else if([result count] > 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s : Error more than 1 target corresponding to the identifier <%@>",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,identifier);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s : Target details successfully fetched for identifier <%@>",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,identifier);

        targetDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        Target * target = [result lastObject];

        [targetDetails setObject:target.firstname  forKey:FIRSTNAME_KEY];
        [targetDetails setObject:target.lastname   forKey:LASTNAME_KEY];
        [targetDetails setObject:target.rank       forKey:RANK_KEY];
        [targetDetails setObject:target.identifier forKey:IDENTIFIER_KEY];

        if(target.photoData)
        {
            [targetDetails setObject:target.photoData  forKey:PHOTODATA_KEY];
        }

        NSSet * emailSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:target.emailList];
        NSSet * phoneSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:target.phoneList];

        [targetDetails setObject:emailSet forKey:EMAILS_KEY];
        [targetDetails setObject:phoneSet forKey:PHONES_KEY];
    }

    return targetDetails ;

}
```

Here is a snippet of the update method. Here I just show the part that updates an email address of a person who's identified with a unique number :

```
+(void) replaceObject:(id)object withObject:(id)newObject forKey:(NSString*)key forIdentifier:(NSNumber*)identifier
{
    if([key isEqualToString:EMAIL_KEY])
    {
        if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [newObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            NSString * email    = (NSString *)object;
            NSString * newEmail = (NSString *)newObject;

            NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Email"];
            NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(email =%@) AND (emailOwner.identifier=%@)",email,identifier];

            request.predicate = predicate ;

            NSError * err ;

            NSArray * result = [DM_CONTEXT executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

            if(err)
            {
                NSLog(@"%s : Error when fetching the email object to be removed for target identifier <%@>",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,identifier);
            }
            else if(![result count])
            {
                NSLog(@"%s : Nothing found.",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
            }
            else if([result count] > 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"%s : Error. More than 1 email object fetched for target identifier <%@>",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,identifier);
            }
            else
            {
                Email * emailToUpdate = [result lastObject];
                emailToUpdate.email = newEmail ;

                if (![DM_CONTEXT save:nil])
                {
                    NSLog(@"%s : Can't Save after updating email! for the identifier <%@>",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,identifier);

                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"%s : Email successfully updated.",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%s : Nothing to replace, or bad objects.",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        }
    }

}
```

The issue is that every other time, after I updated the person's info, when I go back to `viewWillAppear`, `getTargetDetailsForIdentifier:` will not return anything ( the result array is empty).

Comment: And when that happens (the result array is empty) which branch is it taking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> returns to the "PersonDetailsVC" ... In the "PersonsDetailsVC" 's viewDidLoad, I fetch back the person's info and populate the tableviews.

Okay, but this makes no sense. `viewDidLoad` is called only *once* in the view controller's lifetime. You cannot use it to "fetch back the person's info" when you return to it from a modal view controller; it isn't even called.

You should do that sort of work in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

If `viewDidLoad` *is* being called when you return from the modal view controller, then you also have problems with your architecture, i.e. you're not "returning" but creating a completely new view controller, which would also be wrong.

Comment: OK, so if you want more help you probably should show some code.